# Xamarin Forms - Maps - Is possible to call Google Maps from a button?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app and I need to call Google Maps tracing a route from my location to destiny.

I know that I can to do it from maps component and I already did it. But I would like to do it also from a button out of map. Is possible?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call Google Maps with a `Uri` to `Device.Open`, the user can choose how that `Uri` is opened if they have the Google Maps app installed, otherwise they will get the route within their default browser:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit");
Device.OpenUri(uri);
```

You can also do device-specific checks via dependency injection to check if the Google Map app is installed and if so open it directly:

i.e.: On iOS you can check if `comgooglemaps-x-callback:` is available:

```
var canOpenNative = UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("comgooglemaps-x-callback://"));
```

Then you can open it directly via a `Uri` using `comgooglemaps://` or `comgooglemaps-x-callback://` schemes.

```
var uri = new Uri("comgooglemaps-x-callback://?q=dessert&center=37.759748,-122.427135");
```

BTW: Never assume that Google Maps is installed on Android as there are many distributions around the world that install their own mapping apps instead of Googles (This is happens a lot in China, Russia, etc...).

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Solved the problem!

Comment: Xamarin.Essentials Plugin (see @akhil answer) is better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.Essentials use this plugin.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Map.OpenAsync(11.26, 75.78, new MapLaunchOptions { NavigationMode=NavigationMode.Driving});
        //var uri = new Uri("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit");
        //Device.OpenUri(uri);
       // Map.OpenAsync
    }
```

Comment: This is not working in waze maps as expected. It is not evening opening the location. Any solution you did to work on other maps