# How to check some particular application is installed in my device or not in ios using xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**I want to find some particular Application is already installed or not in xamarin forms (I want to implement in android and ios).**

If app is not installed in device then "Install" button is enabled. On Install button click event directly itunes should be open. I also want to search version number.

I have achieved same functionality for android in xamarin forms **but I need help for ios.**

My android code :

```
public class IsAppInstalled : IIsAppInstalled
    {
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }
        public void NavigatePage(string Package_Name)
        {
            try
            {
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=" + Package_Name));
                // we need to add this, because the activity is in a new context.
                // Otherwise the runtime will block the execution and throw an exception
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException)
            {
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + Package_Name));
                // we need to add this, because the activity is in a new context.
                // Otherwise the runtime will block the execution and throw an exception
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        bool IIsAppInstalled.IsAppInstalled(string Appname)
        {
            bool IsInstallflag = false;

            var flag = PackageInfoFlags.Activities;
            var apps = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(flag);
            try
            {
                foreach (var app in apps)
                {
                    var appInfo = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetApplicationInfo(app.PackageName, 0);
                    var appLabel = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetApplicationLabel(appInfo);
                    var versionNumber = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(app.PackageName, 0).VersionName;
                    //var appVersion=Application.Context.PackageManager.
                    if (appLabel.ToLower().Contains(Appname.ToLower()))
                    {
                        //var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        //builder.SetTitle("Found it!");
                        //builder.SetMessage(appLabel + " installed at: " + app.SourceDir);
                        //builder.Show();
                        IsInstallflag = true;
                        //MyVersionName(versionNumber);
                        AppVersion = versionNumber;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return IsInstallflag;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                return IsInstallflag;
            }

        }
    }
```

I have used these classes using dependency injection. This code is perfectly work.

**How to implement same functionality for ios in xamarin forms?**

Comment: You have to know the other app's URL scheme, pre-register the scheme in your app's info.plist and and then you can call `CanOpenUrl` to determine if the user has that app installed : https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl There is no direct equivalence of obtaining all the installed package ids as that is not allowed within iOS.

Comment: You are true. kindly check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone but problem is how to use this method in xamarin forms?  how to define own URL handlers in Info.plist file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781475/xamarin-forms-maps-is-possible-to-call-google-maps-from-a-button/39782171#39782171

Comment: Thanks, Its really helps me but I don't understand what is "comgooglemaps-x-callback://". is it bundle name? I have also tried update info.plist file with the help of following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512228/how-to-check-programatically-if-an-app-is-installed but it didn't work. (Always false as a return value)

Comment: It is one of the iOS URL schemes that google registers for the Map app : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme and also check out the following for Map's `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` for updating your app's `info.plist` : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_7_declare_the_url_schemes_used_by_the_api